# wordpress query first two posts then query remaining posts

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a custom post type, 'product', and I'd like to display the first two, then pull in all remaining posts to display in a separate section of the page. What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

1st `WP_Query` object give you the first two posts. Then store the IDs of those first two posts in array and pass that array in `post__not_in` parameter of 2nd `WP_Query` object.

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'post_type' => 'product',
);
$query_1 = new WP_Query( $args );

$exclude_posts = array();

while ( $query_1->have_posts() ) {
    $query_1->the_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    $exclude_posts[] = get_the_ID();
}

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post__not_in' => $exclude_posts
);
$query_2 = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $query_2->have_posts() ) {
    $query_2->the_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    $exclude_posts[] = get_the_ID();
}
```